# Put SQL and ASP code on a script instead of on my web page

Tags: asp.net, html, sql, vb.net, scripting

Im designing a web site and trying some new concepts. instead of just coding everything onto a web page, i am populating different areas of the page using a database. for example on a news page, i have a drop down to select the story, then I have different areas of the page pull in the headline, story, picture and date which are all stored in the database.  everything is working good. the only thing I want to do is clean up the code a little. Id like for all the connection strings and select statements to be stored in a method on a script or something. and preferably on a HTML page, not an aspx page.

I have a decent amount of knowledge with basic HTML, and some experience programming with Visual Basic.net and SQL.  I am using Visual studio 2012, putting all of this on an ASPX page.

here is an axample of what i have written and working. this displays the headline of the story based off of the value selected in the "NewsDropDown" Drop list.

```
   <%--  displays the headline  --%>
   <asp:FormView ID="NewsHeadlineText" runat="server" 
      DataSourceID="NewsHeadline" class="hdr" 
      meta:resourcekey="NewsHeadlineTextResource1" >
      <ItemTemplate>
          &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="HeadlineLabel" runat="server" 
              Text='<%# Bind("Headline") %>' meta:resourcekey="HeadlineLabelResource1" />
          <br />
      </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:FormView>

  <asp:SqlDataSource ID="NewsHeadline" runat="server" 
      ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:VBallTalksDBConnectionString %>" 
      ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:VBallTalksDBConnectionString.ProviderName %>" 
      SelectCommand="SELECT [Headline] FROM [News] WHERE ([Headline] = ?)">
      <SelectParameters>
          <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="NewsDropDown" Name="Headline" 
              PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
      </SelectParameters>
  </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: You are going to have to use some kind of server-side code to talk to your database. I think you should overcome your resistance to aspx pages, or switch to MVC. SqlDataSource is not really appropriate for anything other than a hobby website; it isn't a good investment of your time to learn that unpopular and outmoded approach.

Comment: @DOK It's interesting your point of view and perspective about the issue mentioned by the op. I still believe that he can use whichever language of his choice with no issues. I would suggest him to create a mockup with static content to test with jsfiddle.net (http://jsfiddle.net/) for us to investigate more.

Comment: ive been away from web design for a few years and was asked to do a page for a friend. so I am pushing myself to learn new things. I kind of was just trying to relate the web site to some of the programming i did.  I have no issue with using an ASPX page, everything is working fine on there and the site is working on my local machine with no issues.  as far as the SqlDataSource being not appropriate, what would you suggest I use? or at least point me in a direction so I can find an alternate way to do it.

Comment: @JoeK as much as I am a .Net developer, I think that if you are only doing light-weight single-page sites, and not full apps, you might be happier using PHP. For starters, check out [this](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/the-best-way-to-learn-php/) and [this](http://devzone.zend.com/6/php-101-php-for-the-absolute-beginner/).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use jQuery's AJAX or a regular AJAX for querying your script that touches the DB in ASP and return the results of the processing in JSON. That way when it comes back you can continue to populate the sections of your website in the programming language of your choice. In PHP with MySQL using AJAX/Javascript and HTML5/CSS3 I have done this in the past with much success, let me know if you have an static mockup in JSFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/) or JSBin if you decide to use Javascript to address your needs

Comment: I havent used JQuery or AJAX at all because I have no experience with them at all. as far as the DB, I am using Sql Server 2008r2.  I was just trying to think of it when I am writing a program, I can write a method, store it in a file, then call it from another method.

Comment: you can create a single html page, and that one to call with AJAX another file, in this case can be an ASP.net page and trigger the processing that you need. I don't understand why the downvote, if it's an idea. Also there are many tutorials online to help doing a basic routine to cast AJAX and apply another file. Also with javascript with you basically write the code as an output to the programming language of your choice, but not to a file, to a variable or a session cookie for example, bottom line- your DBA and ASP skills should be something that you can use at your advantage.

Comment: uh ok :) please create a static prototype (without server side programming languages involved) through jsfiddle or any other. We will be glad to take a look further into the code;